# Marshal 2D array from VB6 to .NET

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, vb6, com-interop

I have a VB6 assembly which I need to use in my .NET application and generated the Interop DLL for usage with .NET via **tlbimp.exe**.

The VB6 assembly has a function that has a byref array parameter. I don't want to change anything in the VB6 assembly, so I hope there is a solution to get the following working.

It is filling the array and I want to use it in my .NET code (c# or vb.net).

Example of the VB6 function (file NativeClass.cls):

```vb
Public Function GetData(ByRef data() As String) As Integer
    Dim tResults() As String
    Dim sRecordCount As String
    Dim lCount As Long

    ' load data
    sRecordCount = dataDummyObject.RecordCount

    ReDim tResults(sRecordCount, 2)

    ' fill the array in a loop
    For lCount = 0 To sRecordCount - 1
        tResults(lCount, 0) = dataDummyObject.Fields("property1")
        tResults(lCount, 1) = dataDummyObject.Fields("property2")

        If (sRecordCount - 1 - lCount) > 0 Then
            Call dataDummyObject.MoveNext
        End If
    End For

    data = tResults
    GetData = sRecordCount
End Function
```

Now I want to use it from VB.NET:

```vb
Private _nativeAssembly As New NativeClass()

Public Function GetDataFromNativeAssembly() As String()
    Dim loadedData As String() = Nothing

    _nativeAssembly.GetData(loadedData)

    Return loadedData
End Function
```

C# version:

```cs
private NativeClass _nativeAssembly = null;

public string[] GetDataFromNativeAssembly()
{
    string[] loadedData = null;

    _nativeAssembly.GetData(loadedData);

    return loadedData;
}
```

But when executing the code I get following Exception:

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeArrayRankMismatchException**: *SafeArray of rank 2 has been passed to a method expecting an array of rank 1.*

I really need help to solve this problem! Thanks for any piece of advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can solve this without modifying the VB6 code. Try declaring the function as

```vb
Public Function GetData(ByRef data As Variant) As Integer
```

or

```vb
Public Function GetData(ByRef data As Object) As Integer
```

The `ReDim` to string array should work fine from Variant. I remember doing it like this all the time because of VB6 not letting a 2D array as a parameter.

When inspecting it from .NET you should see the type. I don't have a VB6 IDE on my machine to verify this.

If one works you should be able to cast over to the `String(,)` you expect.

Comment: not tested, but makes sense. I will accept this as the answer of the question. In the end I build a workaround. Creating a new function in VB6 code which does the same but with structures. Modifying the existing one was not allowed for me (for reasons of binary compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

This is air code, but you could try this in the VB.Net? Note the additional comma to indicate a 2-D array.

```
Dim loadedData As String(,) = Nothing
```

Comment: I tried it, but then Visual Studio gives me an error that the method is a simple string array expecting.

Comment: Which method? The VB6 `GetData`? I know you don't want to change the VB6 but you could try also adding the comma in the VB6 public method declaration like this `Public Function GetData(ByRef data(,) As String) As Integer`

Comment: VB6 does not know about that definition. I get an error when placing the comma between the parentheses. The error from my first comment comes directly from Visual Studio in VB.NET code when calling the interop method.